# Android AccessibilityDelegate force reading of ViewGroup not children

Tags: java, android, android-studio, accessibility, talkback

I'm using a viewpager which is made up of some number of relative layout siblings which are quite complex.

If I click on the relative layout, it will highlight the entire page and read the title and a few textviews one after the other as expected.

If I scroll the viewpager I'd like talkback to read the next page in the same way it reads the first if I click. Secondly, if I scroll to the second, third, etc. pages and click on those layouts, talkback will read as expected.

I am trying to achieve the click behavior after the scroll event has completed.

Here is what I have for the accessibilityDelegate.

```
    viewPager.setAccessibilityDelegate(new AccessibilityDelegate () {
        @Override
        public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED) {
                View page = viewPager.getCurrentPageView();
                performAccessibilityAction(page, AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK, Bundle.EMPTY);
            }
            return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event);
        }
    });
```

I've verified that 'page' is the RelativeLayout parent that I think it is. **I've also confirmed that the `onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent` is being fired, but it doesn't read the contents of its children.** Am I missing something?

**Updated**

I've also tried using

```
viewpager.getCurrentPageView().sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

The above worked for another example when I needed to force talkback to reread a single item but does not have any affect if I try it on the page.

Thanks

Comment: Found solution ?? facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Some background -- When you tap on the relative layout, TalkBack generates speech based on the layout's contents. On ICS, this is triggered by a HOVER_ENTER event. On Jelly Bean, it's triggered by an ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS event. These events are sent automatically by the framework and should, generally speaking, never be sent manually from an app. The same goes for FOCUS events, except in the special case of custom views (see [Accessibility talk from Google I/O 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld7kZRpMGb8) for more details).

So, back on topic.

You can control the speech for SCROLLED events by populating the outgoing event with the text you want read. The down side of this is that you'll need to manually generate the text you want read, and it's very likely that this text will differ from what TalkBack will read if the user touches the layout.

```
viewPager.setAccessibilityDelegate(new AccessibilityDelegate () {
    @Override
    public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);

        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED) {
            event.setContentDescription(/** your text */);
        }
    }
});
```

Another option is to do nothing and let the user explore the view on their own. This is the preferred interaction model for Android accessibility.

**Edit:**  Video URL is broken, Changed.

Comment: does this mean I need to manually recurse through all children and grab the content description?

Comment: I set up the accessibility delegate with onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo, onInitializeAccessibilityEvent, onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, and onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent. the  only one that is firing is onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent. If I set the content description on the event it reads the first time but it looks like the event is reused and it doesn't read the contentDescription set on the event the second, third, ect times.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported on google check

> where ViewPager does not set AccessibilityEvent parameters properly
>   when scrolling.

But after releas of [Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This issue has been resolved.**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. And now I add `android:focusable="true"` to the ViewGroup, the TalkBalk will read the ViewGroup, instead of its children